# Mongo group by nested array, preserving original data Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following Schema, I'm using the Aggregation Framework with mongoose in JS

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: Alfred,
 age: 10,
 orders:[

   {type:"A",address:"Address1"},
   {type:"A",address:"Address2"},
   {type:"B",address:"Address4"},
   {type:"B",address:"Address5"},
   {type:"B",address:"Address6"},
   ...
 ]
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: Bren,
 age: 15,
 orders:[

   {type:"B",address:"Address1"},
   {type:"B",address:"Address2"},
   {type:"B",address:"Address4"},
   {type:"A",address:"Address5"},
   {type:"B",address:"Address6"},
   ...
 ]
}
```

I'm trying to get this output

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: Alfred,
 age:10,

 countTypeA:2,
 countTypeB:3
},
{
 id: 2
 name: Bren,
 age: 15,
 
 countTypeA: 1,
 countTypeB: 4
}
```

I've tried using `$unwind` and `$group:{_id:"orders.type"}` but I'm losing the original data (name, age) for each row, I don't mind losing the address information, I'm interested in counting the type of orders each user has inside their orders list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `orders` array to multiple documents.
2. `$group` - Group by `id` and `orders.type`. And store the other properties via `$first`.
3. `$group` - Group by `id`. Store the other properties via `$first`. And create `type` array with key-value pair document.
4. `$replaceRoot` - Replace the input document with the desired document.
5. `$unset` - Remove `type` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$orders"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        id: "$id",
        type: "$orders.type"
      },
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      age: {
        $first: "$age"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      age: {
        $first: "$age"
      },
      type: {
        $push: {
          k: {
            $concat: [
              "countType",
              "$_id.type"
            ]
          },
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            "$arrayToObject": "$type"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "type"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gmCZzujGmV2)